# How to move branch from one repository to another branch of different repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I created a new Repository (named repoN) with the existing one (named repoE), simply by copying code from the branch (named B22).

After that, I created a new branch in repoN (named BR01).
Now I made some changes in the branch (named BR01) which exist in repoN repository.

I just want to take all those changes into the old repository repoE without loosing history of BR01 into B22.

I am using SourceTree because I'm new in Git and don't know much commands.

Comment: @Adnan: Have a look at [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327171/user-adding-excessive-bolding-in-otherwise-good-edits) about adding bold fonts.  (tl;dr: please don't do it.)

Answer (score 32):

1. stand on your current repo you want to push from
2. checkout the branch you want to push
3. `git remote add repoRemote https://bitbucket/repo/repo1.git`
4. `git push repoRemote`  -- will push your current branch to the remote repo you added in #3

Comment: Do we need to remove the destination repo with git remote remove  repoRemote(not sure if the command is right) to switch to the existing repo once branch is transferred?

Answer (score 13):

At first you need to add to git your destination repository, lets call it `repoE` ( set remote tracking )

```
git remote set-url repoE https://github.com/USERNAME/repoE.git
```

then switch to branch your want to push, assume your branch called `BR01`

```
git checkout BR01
```

and push this branch to destination repository

```
git push repoE BR01
```

Answer (score 2):

In SourceTree, it can be done by adding repoE to Repository->Add Remote so that you can push the changes in repoN to that repo.