# How to copy only single branch from one git repo to another?

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am using the following steps to duplicate all branches to the new-repository.

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
# Make a bare clone of the repository

cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
# Mirror-push to the new repository
```

Now, I have added two new branches in `old-repository.git` and want to move only those 2 branches to `new-repository.git`

What git commands are required to perform it?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but what is your motivation for wanting to move only two branches?

Comment: I am moving from `old-repo` to `new-repo`. I have already moved all the branches to `new-repo` except 2 newly created branches in `old-repo`

Comment: Perhaps you can try just pushing those new branches to the other repository, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118520/how-to-move-branch-from-one-repository-to-another-branch-of-different-repository).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add new_repo as a remote for old repo: this is more convenient for pushing:

```
cd old_repo
git remote add new /path/to/new/repo
git push new newBranch1
git push new newBranch2
```

Answer (score 6):

Clone old branch

```
git clone --single-branch --branch branch_name github_repo_url
```

Tell git where your repo is:

```
git remote add mine your_repo_url
```

Then, push the branch to your repo with:

```
git push -u mine
```

Comment: You don't have to clone your repo, you can directly point to the new one from the old one.

Answer (score 0):

cd old_repo
git remote add new <New_git_repo_cloning_link> 
git push new branchName

Comment: Isn't this essentially what I put in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292372/6309) five years ago?

Comment: Duplicate of already accepted answer